# OS X Sandboxing: LSOpenFromURLSpec() returned -10827

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

We are using a little helper application for starting our main app after login. But we aren't able to launch our main app because LSOpenFromURLSpec() returns the error code -10827.

It doesn't matter if we are using:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"/Applications/Appname.app"];
```

or:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"Appname"];
```

It returns the error everytime. How can we fix that?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: no havn't found a solution yet, that works everytime and on every mac ... :(

Comment: no, there isn't currently any solution ...

Answer (score 5):

According to the LaunchServices headers, that error means it can't find an executable in the app bundle:

```
kLSNoExecutableErr            = -10827, /* The executable is missing*/
```

You allude to OS X sandboxing in your title, so I'm assuming you've run into this problem with a sandboxed app. It's possible that you're not allowed to launch other applications with your app's current entitlements. A simple way to test would be to write an unrestricted command line tool that only calls `-launchApplication:`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"/Applications/Appname.app/Contents/MacOS/Appname"];
```

Comment: The `NSWorkspace` docs explicitly say the full path isn't required.

Comment: @moretension I know what the doc says. This is how I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
NSRunningApplication *newAppRunning = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] options:NSWorkspaceLaunchAsync | NSWorkspaceLaunchNewInstance configuration:nil error:&erroer];
```

This would allow to relaunch the current App. Probably it works if they both are in the same App Group.

see also: [Is it possible to relaunch an app when sandbox deployed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328544/is-it-possible-to-relaunch-an-app-when-sandbox-deployed)